# Add to wishlist button not available for Products in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, wishlist

In admin panel, in customer tab, I have enabled Wishlist option.Still On my homepage , it does not show add to wishlist option for Products .

I have created a custom theme for this.Previously with Luma theme, there was option for wishlist.But on my custom theme, it does not show this option.

This is my static block code to show top Products.

```
{{widget type="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget" display_type="new_products"  products_count="5" template="product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml"}}
```